# For an integral domain $A$, if $\#{\rm Spec}\ A=\infty$, then $\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}\neq (0)}\mathfrak{p}=(0)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $A$ be an integral domain such that $A$ has an infinite number of prime ideals. Then can we say $\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \neq (0)} \mathfrak{p}=(0)$? (Here $\mathfrak{p}$ runs over all prime ideals of $A$ excepting $(0)$).

We can say this if $A$ is a principal ideal domain as follows.

If $f\in \bigcap_{\mathfrak{p}\neq (0)}\mathfrak{p}$ is not $0$,  then we can write $$f=p_1\cdots p_n$$ as product of irreducible elements.
Now since there are infinitely many primes and $A$ is a PID, we can take a prime element $q\in A$ s.t. the prime ideal $(q)$ is not $(p_1),\dotsm, (p_n)$. So $f \notin (q)$ and this is a contradiction.

But I don't know how we can generalize for integral domains $A$ s.t. $A$ is a UFD, or $\dim A=1$ (Krull dimension).

Please show me a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: Your proof does not use that $A$ is a PID anyway, right? You are starting with the assumption that $A$ has infinitely many *prime numbers* (and not just infinitely many prime ideals). So the proof in the case of PID applies here as well.

Comment: If not $A$ is PID, can we take prime ideal $(q)$ as principal ideal？

Comment: Even if $A$ is not a PID, a prime number will always generate a prime ideal (which is all you need in your proof). The thing which can go wrong if $A$ is not a PID is that you may have (nonzero) prime ideals which are not generated by a prime number.

Comment: I'll again point out: You are starting with the assumption that there are infinitely many **prime numbers**, so you can always conjure up a $q$ which is distinct from $p_1, \ldots, p_n$. Moreover, $(q)$ will indeed be a prime ideal.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood yours. Certainly we only should infinitely many prime numbers. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh wait, I just realised that in your proof, you write $f$ as a product of primes. So you're assuming something about $A$ which is more than just a PID, namely that every element does have a prime factorisation. So my previous comments don't apply but at least you've solved the problem for the case where $A$ is a UFD. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An integral domain $A$ satisfying the condition $\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \neq (0)} \mathfrak{p}\ne(0)$ is called a *$G$-domain* (or a *Goldman domain*). So you are actually looking for an integral domain with infinitely many prime ideals which is a $G$-domain. If $A$ is noetherian, then there is no such example since noetherian $G$-domains have only finitely many prime ideals. Mindlack provided a (necessarily) non-noetherian example. Another example is the following: let $R$ be the ring of all algebraic integers, $p\in\mathbb Z$ a prime number and $(P_i)$ all the prime ideals of $R$ lying over $p$. (Note that there are infinitely many prime ideals in $R$ lying over $p$.) Then the ring $A=S^{-1}R$, where $S=R\setminus\bigcup P_i$ is not a $G$-domain since $\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \neq (0)} \mathfrak{p}=(p)$. Moreover, $\dim A=1$.

The question about UFDs has a negative answer: *if a UFD has infinitely many prime ideals, then it is not a $G$-domain*, that is, $\bigcap_{\mathfrak{p} \neq (0)} \mathfrak{p}=(0)$. If a UFD has finitely many irreducibles, then it has finitely many prime ideals; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1907012/121097). Since you assumed that $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is not finite it follows that $A$ has infinitely many non-associated irreducibles, and the proof goes as for PIDs.

Comment: Thank you very much！It’s very surprising that  for only UFD or Noetherian this proposition is true.

Comment: About "If $$ is noetherian, then there is no such example since noetherian -domains have only finitely many prime ideals" , where is this reference? By Wikipedia $\href{here}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_domain}$, this is written in "IRVING KAPLANSKY's Commutative algebra" but in this book there is not such proposition. So Please tell me reference of abstract of proof.

Comment: @Ryu Kaplansky, Theorem 146.

Answer (score 6):

Let $B$ be the subring of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ made with the $f$ such that $f(0) \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $A=S^{-1}B$ where $S=\{f \in B,\, f(0)=1\}$.

Every prime number is a prime element of $A$ so $A$ has infinitely many prime ideals. Moreover, every $f \in B$ can be uniquely written as $ngX^d$ where $d \geq 0, n \in \mathbb{Q}, g \in S$ and $n$ integer if $d=0$. Therefore, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a nonzero prime ideal of $B$ not meeting $S$, $X \in \mathfrak{p}$ or some prime number $q$ is in $\mathfrak{p}$. But, in $B$, $X=q \cdot (X/q)$ so that $X \in \mathfrak{p}$ anyway.

Thus, $X$ is contained in every nonzero prime ideal of $A$, and $A$ is an integral domain with infinitely many prime ideals.

Comment: Why need a prime in $\mathfrak p$? Isn't enough to say that a (non-zero) rational number $n$ is in $\mathfrak p$?

Comment: @user26857: Because $\mathbb{Q} \cap A=\mathbb{Z}$!

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. (I didn't ask why there is a prime number in $\mathfrak p$. This is pretty clear to me. I asked why you need this?)

Comment: Ah. Sorry for misunderstanding. The dichotomy is more like: if there is some nonzero $n \in \mathfrak{p}$, $X=n \cdot (X/n)$ is in $\mathfrak{p}$, otherwise $X$ will be in $\mathfrak{p}$ anyway.